# exporting module in react-native throws error

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
export * as NavigationStyles from './ExNavigationStyles';
```

The above line throws an error in react-native as `

> Unexpected token, expected { (34:7)

Even my Visual Studio Code highlights a syntax error here although this code runs well when I run it in an exponent project. This line is from the **@exponent/ex-navigation** node module from react-native. Is the error because of some incompatible transpiler or the syntax is actually incorrect?

`

Comment: Shouldn't that syntax be just for `import`? I've only ever used `export default [object]` (for example) when setting the export at the bottom of the class/module.

Comment: Hello, @G0dsquad I have edited my question. Please read it again. :)